# Form fields side by side in Drupal Webform

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-forms, drupal-webform

Does anyone know the easiest way to have two form fields in a Drupal Webform display side by side. I am using the Webform module to create a form, but obviously as you create it, all the fields list one right after the other. I have two fields that I would like to have displayed side by side. Is this possible? Oh and I'm using Drupal 6 in case that matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [Arrange Fields](http://drupal.org/project/arrange_fields) module.  This will let you drag and drop and fields anywhere, and should be more than enough to handle what you need.

Comment: Aw man, it doesn't work with multi page forms which is what I am using. :-( Still an awesome module that I will be using in the future. I think I may just use some CSS and float one of the divs unless someone else has a better suggestion.